# How to pass user specified indices into caret trainControl?

Tags: r, cross-validation, indices, r-caret

I am working with a dataset that required a lot of preprocesing and in order to prevent overfitting i constructed the cross-validation folds myself. So i have a dataset where first k records belong to fold 1 (i also have a fold_number column to specify the fold to which a record belongs) second k records belong to fold 2 etc. I want to use caret package and use cross-validation to tune parameters but i cannot figure out how can i pass the ids for each fold to the trainControl() function and not just let R cross-validate for me. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `index` and `indexOut` arguments of `trainControl`.  This is clearly defined in the documentation `??trainControl`

```
...
index       a list with elements for each resampling iteration. 
            Each list element is the sample rows used for training 
            at that iteration.

indexOut    a list (the same length as index) that dictates which sample 
            are held-out for each resample. If NULL, then the unique set 
            of samples not contained in index is used.
...
```

This was also addressed on the mailing list [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-May/277722.html).